# How can I lock a complex operation that uses database read, insert and web access to protect from concurrent access?

Tags: python, sqlite, concurrency, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am building a cache mechanism and it goes like this:

- Try to get a certain field from the database
- If it exists then return it
- If not, then request it from an external API (It should take 500 ms)
- Write it to the database & return it

Example:

```py
    async def _get_poly_id(self, longitude: str, latitude: str):
        poly_id = self._polygon_manager.get_poly_id(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)
        if poly_id == None:
            geo_json = self._point2geojson(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)
            poly_id = await self._agro_api_helper.create_polygon(geo_json) # It can raise exception
            self._polygon_manager.save_poly_id(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude, poly_id=poly_id)
        return poly_id
```

It works well until you try to call this (cache) function concurrently in a non already cached field. At that time:

- All the concurrent requests will check the database
- All they found that there is no cache
- All will call the external API
- The first one will write to the database and return successfully
- The others will try to write again in the database but will get an integrity error (since there is uniqueness in the field)

One workaround would be to handle the Integrity Error and re-check the db. The problem is that the call to the external API costs and must be avoided.

So. Is there a way to lock this operation and make other process wait?
I am using SQLite / SQLAlchemy / FastAPI / Python.

Comment: It sounds like your database read/write operation should be done within a (serializable) transaction.

Comment: Yes..and let the other processes wait. Do you have any idea on how to do this with sqlite/sqlalchemy?

Comment: In the absence of a value in the cache(database), the first db query can create(in the same transaction) a *pending* cache item, parallel queries will return that it is pending and it can be checked later (taking into account the timeout). Then this item is either filled in or deleted when the external api responds

Comment: @alex_noname interesting approach. Is it a common practice?

Comment: This is a common practice for ensuring the idempotency of requests, I just tried to apply it to your case.